# Javascript Ajax : Get the value of an attribute of an ajax response object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function which is calling an ajax request to a webservice.

the result of the ajax call is an object .

Furthemore i need the value of a sepcific attribute of that returned object which is the **responseJSON** when i'm clicking a button

how may i get It ?

**Here is my ajax function:**

```
checkBtnPostulate: function () {
            return $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: annonce.route.testpostulate,
                data: {msg}
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    if (data == 1) {              
                        $("#postulate-btn").removeClass("btn-postuler");
                        $("#postulate-btn #postulerState").text("Retirer la candidature");

                    } else if (data == 0) {       
                        $("#postulate-btn").addClass("btn-postuler");
                        $("#postulate-btn #postulerState").text("Postuler");

                    } else if (data == 2) {        
                        $("#postulate-btn").hide();

                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        },
```

**and here is the function of the click button where i'm using the retur of my previous function.**

```
postulate: function () {
            $('body').one().on('click', '#submitCandidature', function (e) {
                window.annonce.checkBtnPostulate();  //MY PREVIOUS FUNCTION CALL
                var response = window.annonce.checkBtnPostulate(); // the object returned


                if (response.responseJSON == 1) {  // i need to get here the value
                    var FormCandidature = $("#form-candidature");
                    var candidatureObject = serializeObject(FormCandidature);
                    candidatureObject["id_mission"] = id_annonce;
                    var candidatureObject = JSON.stringify(candidatureObject);
                    window.sendData.start(FormCandidature, candidatureObject, "#modal-postuler");

                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        },
```

[image]

**How may i got it on the simpliest way ???**

Comment: if `data` is an object then why is your code comparing it to an interger? `if(data == 1)` would imply that it is a number, not an object..

Comment: have you tried `if (data.responseJSON == 1)` instead of `if (data == 1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the way that I understand what you are asking I would think using a callback in your ajax call would be the best way to achieve what you are looking for the following is what your code would look like using a callback:

```
checkBtnPostulate: function (callback) {
        return $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: annonce.route.testpostulate,
            data: {msg}
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                callback(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    },

 postulate: function () {
        $('body').one().on('click', '#submitCandidature', function (e) {
            window.annonce.checkBtnPostulate(function(data){

 //Confused with what you want but if you have an object off of data you might do something like this
                if(data.responseJSON == 1){
                    var FormCandidature = $("#form-candidature");
                    var candidatureObject = serializeObject(FormCandidature);
                    candidatureObject["id_mission"] = id_annonce;
                    var candidatureObject = JSON.stringify(candidatureObject);
                    window.sendData.start(FormCandidature, candidatureObject, "#modal-postuler");
                }
                if (data == 1) {              
                    $("#postulate-btn").removeClass("btn-postuler");
                    $("#postulate-btn #postulerState").text("Retirer la candidature");

                } else if (data == 0) {       
                    $("#postulate-btn").addClass("btn-postuler");
                    $("#postulate-btn #postulerState").text("Postuler");

                } else if (data == 2) {        
                    $("#postulate-btn").hide();

                }
            }); 


            if (response.responseJSON == 1) {  // i need to get here the value
                var FormCandidature = $("#form-candidature");
                var candidatureObject = serializeObject(FormCandidature);
                candidatureObject["id_mission"] = id_annonce;
                var candidatureObject = JSON.stringify(candidatureObject);
                window.sendData.start(FormCandidature, candidatureObject, "#modal-postuler");

                    }
                })
            }
        });
    },
```

Doing it like this will allow you to directly access the data from your ajax call in your click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
data[ix].attribute
```

ex;

```
data[0].name
```

If there is more than one object in the JSON, you might want to loop through each object?

Tom